# gls file not created

Tags: texstudio, glossaries

Latex does not create a .gls file anymore. I get the following error message:

[image]

I get the same error for my symbols. I am using the package glossaries-extra like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[automake, acronyms, symbols, toc, nonumberlist]{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{AR}{name={AR},description={Auto regression model}}
\newglossaryentry{symb:I}{name={$I$},description={number of agents}, type=symbols}

\begin{document}
\printglossary[title={Abbreviations}]
\printglossary[type=symbols, style=super, title=Symbols]

This is a test \gls{AR}.
```

Could somebody please help me? It worked all fine but suddenly it does not work anymore. I did not change anything. I only added a new abbreviation.

Thank you!!

Comment: have you run makeglossaries and then latex again as in the message that you show?

Comment: I found the problem. It is due to the order of \appendix and \bibliography{library} in my code. If I put \bibliography{library} BEFORE \appendix the .gls file does not update anymore. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Please add your finding about the order of the appendix and bibliography to your question.  Then it will be much more likely to get appropriate attention.

Comment: If the error involves the order of `\appendix` and `\bibliography{library}` then we likely need to see code using those, probably some of your reference(s) will also be involved in the issue.